# How to read the deleted value using a variable

Tags: sql-server, trigger, audit

I'm trying to get 
@OldValue = (select @fieldname from #del) 
 to give me the value. Instead I get the column name for the result.  Is there a way to write this so it can output the value.  If I write it out like this 
@OldValue = (select deleted.ID from #del) 
 I get the correct value. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> If I write it out like this
>   `@OldValue = (select deleted.ID from #del)`
>   I get the correct value.

You only get the correct value if there is a single row being updated or deleted. But Triggers in SQL Server are fired once per DML operation, and the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables contain all of the rows per that operation. So if there were 2 or more rows being updated or deleted, that query, (i.e. `@OldValue = (select deleted.ID from #del)` ) would set the `@OldValue` variable to the value of the `ID` field in the last row of the `deleted` pseudo-table (since each of the previous row's values would get overwritten by the next row).

You need to restructure this in terms of it being a set-based operation. And there are thousands of examples out there (including here on DBA.StackExchange) showing different ways to properly code SQL Server Triggers depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

But regarding being able to use a variable for the column name of the `SELECT` clause, no, that will not work. The best you can do is use Dynamic SQL to construct the `SELECT` statement using the value of the `@FieldName` variable, but since the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables are not available in Dynamic SQL<sup>**</sup>, you would first need to copy `deleted` into a local temporary table which would then be used in the Dynamic SQL to `SELECT` from. But that is a lot of extra I/O and probably not worth doing.

<sup>**</sup> Technically the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables can be accessed in what is effectively Dynamic SQL in SQLCLR Triggers, but that is a much more complex option than is appropriate here.